# Got some strange console errors in firefox when loading spreadjs

Tags: spreadjs, grapecity

[image]Got some undefined errors like **a is undefined**  , **r.spread is defined** from the spreadjs-all.min.js. What are the scenarios for these errors occurs. I have loaded my spreadsheet in an iframe. Is this cause any error ? Only getting this error is firefox.I am using spreadjs version 13.0.1.

My code is below

```
              inframeelm.attr("src", "/engine/packages/components/SpreadJs/index/index.html");
              var contentWindow = inframeelm[0].contentWindow;
              $(contentWindow).ready(function(){
                SpreadSheetGC = contentWindow.GC;
                if(SpreadSheetGC){
                    var designer = SpreadSheetGC.Spread.sheets.Designer;
                    <-----------------------------------------------
                    ------------------------------------------------
                    ------------------------------------------------
                    ------------------------------------------------>
                }
```

designer.loader.ready(function(){}); is not working in my code when I try to implement my functionality inside that.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry I am unable to replicate the error you are seeing. It appears you are working with the SpreadJS Designer source code, please ensure that you follow the Read Me file that describes where to copy/paste SpreadJS's release files to properly use the Designer Source code.

If you have any additional issue feel free to reach out to the SpreadJS support team here and share a sample for us to look deeper into what is causing this issue: [Submit a support ticket](https://www.grapecity.com/support/contact)

Comment: got error TypeError: wrapper.spread is undefined   spreadWrapper.js:82:13  I got the wrapper element but spread is undefined . Is this any intialization error?

Comment: I have added a ticket in support https://supportone.componentone.com/home/casedetail/448613

Comment: Please don't repost [deleted answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62821429/354577). If you can fix an answer that has been deleted, edit it and wait for it to be reviewed.